# Subdomain haproxy for private IP only

Tags: dns, load-balancing, google-compute-engine, haproxy

I use Google Cloud DNS with a network load balancer which itself points to multiple haproxies. I am trying to setup a subdomain which only accepts requests from my VPN.

setup: Cloud DNS -> Load Balancer -> HAProxy

I am using (excerpt) the following frontend rule

```
    acl goodNetwork src 10.218.146.232 //local ip of the ha proxy itself
    acl subdomain hdr(host) -i develop.domain.com
    http-request deny if subdomain !goodNetwork
    use_backend subdomain-backend if subdomain
```

`curl develop.domain.com` from the haproxy server machine itself fails with 403. I tried using ranges, too, but I only got 403s

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try inverting the logic of the http-request, try `http-request allow if subdomain goodNetwork`